# How do I block writing text files in specific directory under a samba share?

Tags: 18.04, server, samba, samba4

I have samba share as follows

```
[g_data]
   path = /g_data2
   browsable = yes
   available = yes
   read only = no
   public = yes
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   create mask = 777
   directory mask = 777
   force create mode = 777
   force directory mode = 777
```

I want to block  writing text files to few sub directories under the main share. I tried adding this line

```
veto files = /*.txt/
```

but this will block text files in all directory. Is there any work around for this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my full smb.conf

```
[global]
    dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
    netbios name = TUB
    realm = UB.LAN
    server role = active directory domain controller
    workgroup = UB

    usershare owner only = false    
    vfs objects = acl_xattr
    map acl inherit = yes
    store dos attributes = yes
    
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes

    logon path = \\%L\profiles\%U

[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/ub.lan/scripts
    read only = No

[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = No
    
[profiles]
    path = /var/lib/samba/profiles
    read only = no
    profile acls = yes

[data]
    path = /data
    browsable = yes
    available = no
    read only = no
    
[r_data]
    path = /r_data
    browsable = yes
    available = yes
    read only = yes
    public = yes
    writable = no
    guest ok = yes

[g_data]
    path = /g_data2
    browsable = yes
    available = yes
    read only = no
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
    force create mode = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
    force group = nogroup
    veto files = /*.txt/
```

Comment: Did you added this line in `[global]` or `[g_data]`? Can you share your full config? Edit your entry…

Comment: I had edited and put my complete smb.conf @moep

Comment: The `veto` specification hides the files but does not prevent creating them.  I think you will have to use file permissions to block creation of files but I do not see any way to prevent creation based on the name.  I wonder what you want to achieve: if a user has a text file, he could save it as .CSV (or whatever extension) but not as .txt?

Comment: by providing veto files like above, users are stopped from creating *.txt file in that network share. I w just want to know is this can be done to sub directories under this network share. That is we dont want to create *.txt file in certain folder. @ Marc Vanhoomissen